# Network speed issue - Phone achieves much faster speeds than my laptop on the same network

Tags: windows, windows-10, internet, wifi-driver

I’m having a issue with the internet speed on my laptop at school.

My laptop has a very hard time achieving **20Mbps** down and **10Mbps** up though the network adapter supports **100Mbps**.

Meanwhile my iPhone 8 achieves **120Mbps** up and down on the exact same network.

I don’t know what causes this, but it’s very frustrating that the speed is so slow on my laptop.

This is the WiFi adapter in my laptop:

```
Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11 bgn Wi-Fi Adapter
```

Answer (score 6):

It appears the iPhone 8 supports the 802.11ac Wi-Fi standard (https://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_8-8573.php) which has a theoretical maximum throughput about 3 times that of 802.11n which your laptop supports (https://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2014/12/30/802-11ac-vs-802-11n-wifi-whats-the-difference/#4e26bf3b3957).

Yes, your laptop is achieving far less than the theoretical maximum speed of 802.11n, but that could be to do with a number of things. 802.11ac on your iPhone could be using a different frequency band (5GHz), and maybe the 2.4GHz band is saturated by a lot of devices, leaving the 5GHz band relatively free. It could also just be related to the Wi-Fi hardware installed at your school.

It's difficult to pinpoint the actual cause without a lot more information, but suggest plugging in a USB 802.11ac Wi-Fi adapter to your laptop, switch over to that rather than the onboard Realtek, and see if your speeds improve. You can find the adapters for under $20 (https://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-5520_T4U-V2.html)

Comment: Assuming that the 802.11AC adapter does improve things, it might also be worth looking into just replacing the integrated adapter in the laptop, which should in theory provide even better performance than the USB adapter.